# Calculating the intersection coordinates given by 2coordinates and the radius

Tags: python, coordinate

Basically I have 2 coordinates and 2 radius provided.

**This are:**

`x1= 3.540437, y1 = 103.4278, d1 = 4m`

`x2 = 3.540485,y2 = 103.4278, d1 = 1m`

Is there any way to calculate the latitude and longitude of the intersection ?

Comment: possibly duplicate of [Find the intersection between two geographical data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431528/find-the-intersection-between-two-geographical-data-points).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But i have read through in it . Inside using "pyproj" but i have no this module in my python. Currently i am working it using Lopy and using the Pymakr software. Is it applicable ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the intersection between two geographical data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431528/find-the-intersection-between-two-geographical-data-points)

Comment: It's a duplicate.